# ¿Por qué se me pierden los datos cuando hago un 'suscribe'?

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, http

Tengo problemas al asignar a una variable los datos que traigo de una petición http. Cuando está dentro del 'suscribe' se asigna bien los datos a la variable que tengo y cuando sale del 'suscribe' esa variable queda en 'undefined', es un poco confuso porque ya obtengo datos en otro componente sin problemas. Acá abajo dejo un poco del código para ver si se entiende:

```
      //esto es del componente


   ngOnInit() {
     this.getProveedor();
   }


 public getProveedor(){
  var nombre: string = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('nombre');
  this.proveedorService.findByNombre(nombre).subscribe(datos=>{

 this.proveedor = datos;    
 console.log(this.proveedor);    //acá me muestra bien los datos asignados a this.proveedor    
 }
  });
console.log(this.proveedor);     // acá, fuera del suscribe, this.proveedor queda undefined
}


  // es el método del servicio

   findByNombre(nombre: string):Observable<any>{
    return this._http.get(this.urlFinal+nombre, nombre);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

`subscribe` es una operación que se ejecuta de manera asíncrona y por ende no sabemos cuando terminará. `console.log` se ejecuta automaticamente despues de que lanzas el `subscribe` pero al ser síncrona no espera a que termine la ejecución del subscribe y lo que en realidad te está mostrando no es una pérdida de datos, si no la variable sin datos. Es hasta después que se reciben los datos que se cargan estos.

Angular escucha los cambios que hagas en tu componente y los refleja automáticamente en el html después de la asignación. Así que lo que ves es un comportamiento normal.

> Más información https://angular.io/guide/architecture

Comment: Alguna idea de lo que debería leer para entender y poder arreglar lo que intento hacer?

Comment: @kokuone Edite la pregunta con la referencia.